# Schroedinger equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can one numerically solve the nonlinear stationary Schroedinger equation in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Time dependent or time independent?

Comment: which non-linear term?

Comment: stationary (i.e. time-independent) with a mean-field nonlinearity (|psi|^2*psi)